# Search a list with words in string as parameter in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, search, operator-keyword

I could use some advice, how to search in a list for genres with words in a string as parameter.

So if i have created a list called genre, which contains a string like:

```
['crime, drama,action']
```

I want to use this list to search for movies containing all genres or maybe just 1 of them.

I have created a big list which contains all information about the movie. An example from the list you see here:

```
('Saving Private Ryan (1998)', '8.5', "Tom Hanks, Matt Damon, Tom Sizemore',\n", 'action, drama, war,\n'),
```

So if i want to search for saving private ryan, which is a drama + action genre, but not crime, how can i then use my genre list to search for it?

Is there a way to search by something in the string?

**UPDATE:**

So this is what i done so far. I have tried to precess my tuple movie and use the def function.

```
Navn_rating = dict(zip(names1, ratings))

Actor_genre = dict(zip(actorlist, genre_list))

var = raw_input("Enter movie: ")
print "you entered ", var

for row in name_rating_actor_genre:
    if var in row:
        movie.append(row)

print "Movie found",movie

def process_movie(movie):
    return {'title': names1, 'rating': ratings, 'actors': actorlist, 'genre': genre_list}
```

Comment: I think you should change your data structure. Consider making each film a dictionary e.g. `{'title': 'Saving Private Ryan', 'year': 1998, 'rating': 8.5, 'actors': ['Tom Hanks', ...], 'genres': ['action', ...]}` then your query becomes `if 'drama' in movie.genres and 'action' in movie.genres:`. Stuffing more strings into a tuple isn't helping anyone.

Comment: Is there an easy way to make a dict when i already have a list with all the information? 

I'm not the best python programmer, and never really used dictionary before

Comment: You should really get to grips with dictionaries, they're a very powerful tool. Try reading [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). I have written my comment up into an answer, adding some pointers on switching to a dictionary - I think this will make the rest of your code much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can *"search by something in the string"* using `in`:

```
>>> genres = 'action, drama, war,\n'
>>> 'action' in genres
True
>>> 'drama' in genres
True
>>> 'romantic comedy' in genres
False
```

But note that this might not always give the result you want:

```
>>> 'war' in 'award-winning'
True
```

I think you should change your data structure. Consider making each movie a dictionary e.g.

```
{'title': 'Saving Private Ryan', 'year': 1998, 'rating': 8.5, 'actors': ['Tom Hanks', ...], 'genres': ['action', ...]}
```

then your query becomes

```
if 'drama' in movie.genres and 'action' in movie.genres:
```

You can use indexing, `split` and slicing to process your tuple of strings to make the values of the dictionary, e.g.:

```
>>> movie = ('Saving Private Ryan (1998)', '8.5', "Tom Hanks, Matt Damon, Tom Sizemore',\n", 'action, drama, war,\n')
>>> int(movie[0][-5:-1])
1998
>>> float(movie[1])
8.5
>>> movie[0][:-7]
'Saving Private Ryan'
>>> movie[2].split(",")
['Tom Hanks', ' Matt Damon', " Tom Sizemore'", '\n']
```

As you can see, some tidying up may be needed. You could write a function that takes the tuple as an argument and returns the corresponding dictionary:

```
def process_movie(movie_tuple):
    # ... process the tuple here
    return {'title': title, 'rating': rating, ...}
```

and apply this to your list of movies using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
movies = list(map(process_movie, name_rating_actor_genre))
```

**Edit**:

You will know your function works when the following line doesn't raise any errors:

```
assert process_movie(('Saving Private Ryan (1998)', '8.5', "Tom Hanks, Matt Damon, Tom Sizemore',\n", 'action, drama, war,\n')) == {"title": "Saving Private Ryan", "year": 1998, "rating": 8.5, "actors": ["Tom Hanks", "Matt Damon", "Tom Sizemore"], "genres": ["action", "drama", "war"]}
```

Comment: No, the argument is one tuple from the "big list" - `map` is used to apply the same function to every tuple in the list.

Comment: Just use what you're already doing, presumably something like `zip(titles, ratings, actors, genres)` - you can plug this straight in: `movie_dicts = list(map(process_movie, zip(titles, ratings, actors, genre)))`. The use of `map` means you don't need a `for` loop.

Comment: @Raaydk that update hasn't really changed anything. Simply read my previous comment and adjust the variable names accordingly.

Comment: `print movie_dicts`? But, to save you time: that function is definitely not going to work. Try developing and testing the function separately, using the example "Saving Private Ryan" tuple from your question, then apply it to the whole zipped list once it's working.

Comment: @Raaydk I have no idea what that comment means. I know you have 4 lists, but the function should take a tuple (like the one in your question) as an argument, process it and return a dictionary for one single movie.

Comment: So what about now.. is this what you were trying to get me to do?

Comment: @Raaydk no. I have added an `assert` in an edit; when that passes, your function works. Note that you will need some lines of code like the processing ones I have included in my answer between the `def` and the `return`!